# How to do more customization zeppelin notebook?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Hortonworks sandbox under the version of 2.5. The zeppelin service running successfully, when i create a zeppelin notebook with sample data in csv file, For eg; list of data available below wise;

```
+----------------------------------------+
| id  name specialization county   state |
+----------------------------------------+
| 001 xxxx Android       Bronx     NY    |
+----------------------------------------+
| 002 yyyy ROR           Rome      NY    |
+----------------------------------------+
| 003 zzzz Bigdata       Bronx     NY    |
+----------------------------------------+
| 004 pppp IOS           Dallas    TX    |
+----------------------------------------+
| 005 qqq  IOS           Dallas    TX    |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I have a pie,bar charts,sql table.In pie chart list of states available like TX with respective count on pie chart.
[image]

When i click over pie chart for the value TX portion, i want do dynamically data has been filtered in the entire notebook in all widgets like sql table,bar chart,etc. But i got all data has been display in sql table and below table contain 70,000 records, i want only tx state records only. 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Please tell me how do i make this functionality in zeppelin.

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.7.0, you can create your own charts like https://github.com/1ambda/zeppelin-highcharts-columnrange.

It's called **Helium (Pluggable) Visualization (Chart)**

Here are some resources you can refer

- All available helium visualizations: http://zeppelin.apache.org/helium_packages.html
- How to write new helium visualization: http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/development/writingzeppelinvisualization.html
- Zeppelin built in samples: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/tree/branch-0.7/zeppelin-web/src/app/visualization/builtins

Comment: Thanks for the response. is it possible in helium?. Why i'm asking if i select particular portion in pie chart that value only filtered in sql table,bar chart,etc. And in zeppelin i can't able to select portion of pie chart.

Comment: It would be nice if you add some screenshots to explain what you want.

Comment: Please find my above updated post with some screenshot, i have taken from zeppelin-notebook.

Comment: Zeppelin built-in pies chart use nvd3 library. I am not sure nvd3 supports that functionality. And, I think this is what you want: **drill down pie chart** (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown). You can use this drill down pie chart to create your own helium visualization.

Comment: If you are using 0.7.0+ (helium is supported as of 0.7.0), I can create it until this weekend for you. Please tell me if you want. Of course, you can create too.

Comment: Now i understand fully what you want to do. You want to filter table by clicking pie chart right?

Comment: Yes correct. Thanks for the response. I have already seen this pie-chart drilldown. But I don't how to use in Zeppelin. My aim is if one widget get affected, entire notebooks filtered.

Comment: Currently, there is no such feature and I think it is quite big feature and requires new UI component.

Comment: Isn't possible in Zeppelin? Please tell me, if I'm using some external plugins like nvd3,highcharts wise also I can't implement? Give me some suggestion.

Comment: It beyonds helium visualization. I would not say it's really impossible, cause you can create PR for that.

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestion. I will try using helium visualization. It is more important, if i implement it would more useful for end user.